# How to create file names using parameters defined in my code

Tags: files-and-directories, save

In the first line of my code the values of `m` and `n` are decided. After running it, three important lists are generated, say `list1`, `list2` and `list3`. I am using

```
Save["list1-mn.m", list1]
Save["list2-mn.m", list2]
Save["list3-mn.m", list3]
```

at the final to save the results. But I have to change the name of these files every time I ran the code for different values of `m` and `n`, to avoid subscribing. Is there a way to auto change the name of the files according to the values of `m` and `n`? For example, if I put `m=3` and `n=5` at the beginning of the code, I have to change the scope of `Save` **manually** to

```
Save["list1-35.m", list1]
Save["list2-35.m", list2]
Save["list3-35.m", list3]
```

before running the code. Is there a way to do this automatically? For me, it is important to save the files, no matter if the function used is `Save` or another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to change the scope of Save manually to
>
> Save["list1-35.m", list1] Save["list2-35.m", list2] Save["list3-35.m",
>   list3]

You could try this and see if it works for you. Not tested.

```
n=2;
m=3;
(*list1,list2,list3 ready here*)
Do[
  fileName="list"<>ToString[k]<>"-"<>ToString[n]<>ToString[m]<>".m";
  Save[fileName,ToExpression["list"<>ToString[k]]]
  ,
  {k,1,3}
]
```

Comment: Can we do this with StringFormat?